# Selecting radio button with dynamic id in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I select a radio button in java selenium webdriver that has an appended dynamic id. I don't have the ability to determine before hand the number that is appended. So I need a way to select via partially matching text while ignoring that last number.

```
id=edit-emergency-notification-status-existing-message-7
```

!"7" is generated with each new item created in this screen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPY4a.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it **by xpath** with the help of `starts-with()`:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, "edit-emergency-notification-status-existing-message-")]
```

Comment: I am getting: 

`org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector [starts-with(@id, "edit-emergency-notification-status-existing-message-")] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression [starts-with(@id, "edit-emergency-notification-status-existing-message-")] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`

Comment: @3ck are you sure you are using the same exact expression as in the answer?

Comment: I am using it in a By:

`private By alertRadioButton = By.xpath("[starts-with(@id, \"edit-emergency-notification-status-existing-message-\")]");`

Comment: @3ck and what about the `//*` part at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS selector and use starts with wild character (^)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id^='edit-emergency-notification-status-existing-message']"));
```